# GWT CellList backed with ListDataProvider too slow

Tags: java, gwt

The list is populated with lots of data (on average 5000 cells) and works too slow, especially when I try to use a quick search on data. Is there any approach to improve CellList performance?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some code

Answer (score 2):

I suggest implementing paging and binding the CellList to an asyncDataProvider instead.

If you need to search all data, run the search server side before the dataset is returned.